# How do you grant a user access to create webhooks in Phabricator?

Tags: phabricator

I know that webhooks are available in Herald > Webhooks in Phabricator, but I can't figure out how to grant access to this function. When I click the button I see the message: You do not have permission to create these objects.

Does anyone know how to grant access to create webhooks?

Answer (score 0):

You can promote an user from standard user to Administrator to grant access to Phabricator webhooks.

> Users must have the "Can Create Webhooks" permission to create new
> webhooks.
>
> ― [Phabricator Webhooks documentation](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/webhooks/)

If you need further customization, visit this URL and change the default:

- `http://example.com/applications/view/PhabricatorHeraldApplication/`

Comment: Hi @amorrise have you tried this solution?